# how to insert data with subquery that returns more than on value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have two tables `company_list` and `company_details`. The `company_list` table has a `company_id` column, and the `company_details` has some information related to the company with the `company_id`. I wanted to insert data into the `company_details` table with the `company_id` not in the `company_details` table.
I tried it with the following query but it gave me an error.

```
INSERT INTO company_details (company_id,detail_found)
VALUES ((SELECT company_id FROM company_list WHERE company_id  NOT IN (SELECT company_id FROM company_details)), 'No data found');
```

**The error is:**

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

How to insert data into the table with a subquery that returns more than one value?

Comment: use a simple `INSERT INTO . . . SELECT ... FROM` query

Answer (score 2):

You can use an insert-select statement (without the `values` clause), and query the string literal as one of the select's columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO company_details (company_id,detail_found)
SELECT company_id, 'No data found' 
FROM   company_list 
WHERE  company_id NOT IN (SELECT company_id FROM company_details)
```